# Set current index of QComboBox inside QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have `QComboBox` inside `QTableWidget`. It was created like this:

```
QComboBox* bb = new QComboBox(this);
ui->propsWidget->setCellWidget(1, 0, bb);
for (...)
    bb.addItem(...);
```

I need to set its index programmatically. I've tried this:

```
QComboBox* bb = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(ui->propsWidget->cellWidget(1, 0));
bb->setCurrentIndex(5);
```

and this:

```
bb->setEditText("mytext"); // "mytext" is contained in bb
```

but the current index is not changing. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify this line: `QComboBox* bb = new QComboBox(this);` because `QTableWidget` takes the ownership of all its subcomponents. So, it must become `QComboBox* bb = new QComboBox();`, and the parent will be the table on its own.

Comment: So then how could I delete it after closing the dialog?

Comment: Qt has its destruction mechanism. When you delete `QTableWidget`, all its children including `QComboBox` will be automatically deleted too.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But I don't understand how the ownership is influencing access to widgets.

Comment: @MichaelO. When you declare `ComboBox* bb = new QComboBox(this);`, you make the combobox a child of the current widget not the tablewidget. However, any method from the tablewidget works fine if and only if the widget is a child of the table.